# Call a function from a view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a method that I can call from different viewControllers.

I have a class called Info.h/Info.m and in this I have a method: -

```
-(void) testFunc {
 ... Do something here
}
```

I then want to call this function in my ViewController. I tried the following but I can't get the testFunc to run.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Info.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Info *targetsInstance = [[Info alloc] init];
    [targetInstance testFunc];

}

@end
```

When I type [targetInstance testFunc] I get the error "No visible @interface for 'Info' declares the selector 'testFunc'"

Comment: Please provide more information about, your apps architecture / how your app is organized. Whats the purpose of the info class, and what do you want to do? :)

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work". That's a useless term. Be specific about the problem.

Comment: BTW - please follow proper naming conventions. Class names should begin with uppercase letters. Method and variable names being with lowercase letters.

Comment: When I say 'it doesn't work' I mean that the code in testFunc doesn't run. in fact when I type [targetInstance testFunc] I get the error "No visible @interface for 'Info' declares the selector 'testFunc'"

Comment: please see the edited answer. And hope it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Info.h` file, you must declare `-(void) testFunc` as a method in the `@interface` section

```
@interface Info: UIViewController {
}

-(void) testFunc;

@end
```

Comment: sorry I typed it incorrectly in my example (I corrected my code), I have exactly what you typed here however I get an error message of "No visible @interface for 'Info' declares the selector 'testFunc'"

Answer (score 1):

assuming you declared the `info` class (I recommend using a capital letter for class names) correctly replace this:

```
[info testFunc];
```

with:

```
[targetsInstance testFunc];
```

Since the method is an instance method (due to the '-' character) you need an instance for invoking it.

Comment: When you say declaring the class what do you mean?