# How to create a function that is accessible from a viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to define a method to show and hide progress bars in my application. However, I don't want to create local methods for these in each view controller. How do I define global method which takes views as parameters and does something with them.

Here is what I tried:

```
import Foundation
import MBProgressHUD

public class ShowLoading{

    let view = UIView()

    func show(){
        let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(view, animated: true)
        loadingNotification.color = UIColor.blueColor()
        loadingNotification.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.Indeterminate
        loadingNotification.labelText = MyConstants.LOADING_TEXT
    }

    func hide(){
        MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(view, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a function from a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262540/call-a-function-from-a-view)

Comment: Define your methods as static and make them accept parameters like so: static func test(view: UIView)

Comment: You can define your methods in AppDelegate class and you can easily get presented view controller instance and show hud over that controller. However you can also show the hud on UIWindow instance of application .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make one BaseViewController class inherited with UIViewController

Now create you method in BaseViewController

```
func show() {
let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(view, animated: true)
    loadingNotification.color = UIColor.blueColor()
    loadingNotification.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.Indeterminate
    loadingNotification.labelText = MyConstants.LOADING_TEXT
}   

func hide(){
    MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(view, animated: true)
}
```

Now inherit this BaseViewController to you ViewController where you want to show progress bar, then just call **self.show()** and **self.hide()**

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `let view = UIView()`, no need of that.
And add parameter to method like :

```
func show(view: UIView) {

    let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(view, animated: true)
    loadingNotification.color = UIColor.blueColor()
    loadingNotification.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.Indeterminate
    loadingNotification.labelText = MyConstants.LOADING_TEXT
}
```